# In HTML table - single cell has multiple lines. How to give each line Different size and alignment

Tags: html, css, line, cell

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .chess-board { border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; }
            .chess-board th { padding: 1000px; }
            .chess-board th + th { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
            .chess-board th:first-child,
            .chess-board td:last-child { border-right: 1px solid #000; }
            .chess-board tr:last-child td { border-bottom: 1px solid; }
            .chess-board th:empty { border: none; }
            .chess-board td { width: 2000px; height: 2000px; text-align: center; font-size: 2000px; line-height: 0; }
            .chess-board .light { background: white; }
            .chess-board .dark { background: green; }
            .button { width: 500px; height: 200px; font-size: 50px;line-height:0;font-weight: bold;border: 10px solid black; }
            .letters { width: 500px; height: 500px; text-align: center; font-size: 600px; line-height: 0; }            
        </style>
    </head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <table id="Chess_Board" class="chess-board">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="letters">a</th>
                    <th class="letters">b</th>
                    <th class="letters">c</th>
                    <th class="letters">d</th>
                    <th class="letters">e</th>
                    <th class="letters">f</th>
                    <th class="letters">g</th>
                    <th class="letters">h</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">8</th>
                    <td class="light">♜</td>
                    <td class="dark">♞</td>
                    <td class="light">♝</td>
                    <td class="dark">♛</td>
                    <td class="light">♚</td>
                    <td class="dark">♝</td>
                    <td class="light">♞</td>
                    <td class="dark">♜</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">7</th>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                    <td class="dark">♟</td>
                    <td class="light">♟</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">6</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">5</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">4</th>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">3</th>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                    <td class="dark"></td>
                    <td class="light"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">2</th>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                    <td class="light">♙</td>
                    <td class="dark">♙</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="letters">1</th>
                    <td class="dark">♖</td>
                    <td class="light">♘</td>
                    <td class="dark">♗</td>
                    <td class="light">♕</td>
                    <td class="dark">♔</td>
                    <td class="light">♗</td>
                    <td class="dark">♘</td>
                    <td class="light">♖</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <button class="button" onclick="Screenshot()">Download as Png</button>
        <br>
    </body>
    <script>
        function Screenshot(){
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#Chess_Board")).then(canvas => {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        });}
    </script>
</html>
```

here is the result[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sZq3.jpg

now i want a and 8 inside the ROOK's Cell like [marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBAUR.png)

please help me i have been trying so many days for this answer.

................................................................
......................................0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Start by wrapping each of them into something like a `span`, so that you can apply formatting to each of them individually.

Comment: The letters in your "what I want" image appear to have different sizes, yet the comments in the HTML you gave say `200px` for all of them. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry my bad. I need different font size for each line

Answer (score 0):

That is perfect work for CSS Grid:

1. Set wrapper to be `display: grid`
2. Set items position in places where you want it to be

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: grid;
}

.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.middle {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.top {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.bottom {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.left {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.right {
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top left">a</div>
  <div class="middle">b</div>
  <div class="bottom right">c</div>
</div>
```